# Kill client connection to Cassandra instance

Tags: cassandra

Not able to go to find any documentation on how to kill a client connection to remote Cassandra I will instance .. as a DBA at the server end?
Seems like an easy task but why no mention of this in Cassandra documentation...

PL help
Thanks